# How to achieve a hover effect on a sphere in Three.js to change color when mouseover?

Tags: three.js, hover

how to achieve hover effect with changing color?
how to achieve hover effect with changing color?
how to achieve hover effect with changing color?

Hello community,

I've successfully implemented a feature where the color of a sphere changes when I click and hold the mouse button. However, I want to achieve the same effect without requiring a click, only by hovering the mouse over the sphere.Hello community,

I've successfully implemented a feature where the color of a sphere changes when I click and hold the mouse button. However, I want to achieve the same effect without requiring a click, only by hovering the mouse over the sphere.

Here's a snippet of my current code:\Hello community,

I've successfully implemented a feature where the color of a sphere changes when I click and hold the mouse button. However, I want to achieve the same effect without requiring a click, only by hovering the mouse over the sphere.

Here's a snippet of my current code:
Hello community,

I've successfully implemented a feature where the color of a sphere changes when I click and hold the mouse button. However, I want to achieve the same effect without requiring a click, only by hovering the mouse over the sphere.

Here's a snippet of my current code:

Here's a snippet of my current code:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import './style.css';
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
import gsap from "gsap";

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
// Create our sphere
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 64, 64);
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: "#00ff83",
});
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

// Sizes
const sizes = {
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
};

// Light
const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 70, 100, 1.7);
light.position.set(0, 10, 10);
scene.add(light);

// Camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, sizes.width / sizes.height);
camera.position.z = 20;
scene.add(camera);

// Renderer
const canvas = document.querySelector(".webgl");
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
renderer.setPixelRatio(2);
renderer.render(scene, camera);

// Controls
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.enablePan = false;
controls.enableZoom = false;
controls.autoRotate = true;
controls.autoRotateSpeed = 10;

// Resize
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  // Update Sizes
  sizes.width = window.innerWidth;
  sizes.height = window.innerHeight;
  // Update Camera
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height;
  renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
});

const loop = () => {
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};
loop();

// Timeline magicccc
const tl = gsap.timeline({ defaults: { duration: 1 } });
tl.fromTo(mesh.scale, { z: 0, x: 0, y: 0 }, { z: 1, x: 1, y: 1 });
tl.fromTo('nav', { y: '-100%' }, { y: '0%' });
tl.fromTo('.title', { opacity: 0 }, { opacity: 1 });

// MouseAnimationColorrr
let mouseDown = false;
let rgb = [];
window.addEventListener("mousedown", () => (mouseDown = true));
window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => (mouseDown = false));

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (mouseDown) {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  5
);
camera.position.z = 2;
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 64, 64); // Keep in mind these sizes
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: "#00ff83",
});
const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 70, 100, 1.7);
light.position.set(0, 10, 10);
scene.add(light);
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

function onMouseMove(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(mesh);
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    mesh.material.color.set(0x00ff00);
  } else {
    mesh.material.color.set(0xff0000);
  }
}
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.webglHH {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.159.0/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="webglHH"> </canvas>
```

Let's switch to English so that other users don't have to translate, and moderators can also delete posts that are not in English. ;)
Implementing three js into builders like Elementor or Divi can be quite troublesome... I remember that I tried something with Elementor a long time ago, but the performance was very poor, secondly, Elementor creates its layers in the DOM, which can be troublesome in finding or scaling (elements/objects) on the scene . It's best to work in pure 3js or r3f without wordpress or other drag&drop builders.

Comment: First of all, I would like thank you for an answer, but the problem is that it's not working. Your code changed the color of sphere to red, but it's still the same; no hover effect. Could You look on it once again?

Comment: Sorry, I’m writing from phone, but check update above, I added if statement

Comment: widzę, że jesteśmy rodakami; może przerzućmy się na ojczysty :).
Słuchaj, już kilka osób nie jest w stanie mi z tym pomóc. Przejrzyj to proszę jeszcze raz.. Do tego od razu będę miał drugie pytanie, jak to wrzucić do elementora pro na Wordpress? jak to wrzucam nie działa, nie wyświetla kuli. Gdy dla próby wklejałem gotowe kody np. z codepen, działają, ale mój kod nie działa.

Comment: nadal nie działa, niestety. Brak hover. Muszę klikać myszka, żeby się kula kręciła.

Comment: Check update...

Comment: Add to animate mesh.rotation.x += 0.01; mesh.rotation.y += 0.01; And BTW I will give you small advice, because you are new Member. Personally, I'm not very sensitive, but you'll find people on this forum who are. And they have much less patience than me. What do you mean "...that this color transition looks very amateurish..."? You asked a simple question "How to achieve a hover effect on a sphere in Three.js to change color when mouseover?" And you got what you asked for. You don't really think that someone here will prepare a transition for you straight from Awwwards projects, do you?

Comment: Tak, jestem nowym członkiem na tej stronie. Nie chciałem Cię urazić i podziękowałem Ci za to, że mi odpisałeś. Jednak dobrze wiesz, że to wyglada amatorsko. Do takiej zmiany samemu bym doszedł. Nie jest ona płynna, a przy tym kula przestaje się ruszać kompletnie, dobrze wiesz o co mi chodzi. Jednak i tak dziękuję jeszcze raz za poświęcony czas

Comment: Nie uraziłeś mnie. Powinineś zrozumieć, że ta strona może dać Ci kierunek rozumowania co do jakiejś funkcjonalności, a też często samo rozwiązanie. Nigdzie nie sprecyzowałeś jak ma wyglądać to przejście pomiędzy kolorami. Tak szczerze to nawet nie wiem co masz na myśli, poza zmianą koloru na hover. Pytanie nie dotyczyło "nieamatorskiego" przejścia pomiędzy kolorami na hover. A gdyby dotyczyło, to pewnie Moderatorzy zamknęliby ten wątek, i powiedzieli Ci, że nikt nie będzie robił UX za Ciebie.